# Eigen3 A.ldlt().solve(b) wrong sign

Tags: c++, solver, eigen3

I want to solve the following dense system with Eigen3: `A * x + b = 0`

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 8, 8> A;
A << 3.333e-05, 0, 0, 1.666e-05, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5,
    0, 3.333e-05, 0, 0, 1.666e-05, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 3.333e-05, 0, 0, 1.666e-05, 0, 0,
    1.666e-05, 0, 0, 3.333e-05, 0, 0, -0.5, -0.5,
    0, 1.666e-05, 0, 0, 3.333e-05, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1.666e-05, 0, 0, 3.333e-05, 0, 0,
    -0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    -0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1;

Eigen::Matrix<double, 8, 1> b;
b << -320, 0, 0, 300, 0, 0, -320, -300;

Eigen::Matrix<double, 8, 1> x1 = A.ldlt().solve(-b); // wrong sign
Eigen::Matrix<double, 8, 1> x2 = -A.inverse() * b; // OK
```

The exact solution is (`x2`):

```
200040, 0, 0, 200040, 0, 0, 320, 300
```

However, using `ldlt()`, the solution (`x1`) I get is:

```
199420, 0, 0, 200660, 0, 0, -300.01, -320.01
```

I'm sure there must be something I don't understand, since:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 8, 1> x3 = A.transpose().ldlt().solve(-b);
```

gives the desired result.

Comment: Your matrix is not symmetric

Comment: ok, I didn't know it had to be, didn't find it in the docs. Which solver should I use?

Comment: @mfnx check out a table here https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html

Comment: additionally, the determinant of your matrix is really small, and solving this system as given can face numerical instabilities, consider using a preconditioner

Comment: Indeed, the documentation fails to note that Cholesky decompositions only work for symmetric/self-adjoint matrices (this was probably too obvious for the person that initially wrote this ...) I would suggest trying `FullPivLU`, `ColPivHouseholderQR` or `FullPivHouseholderQR`. The SVD-solvers should also work, but are probably overkill.